# Why does height behave so differently in firefox with absolute div?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, absolute

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yqL9uo63/1/

The source code is really simple. If you open the above fiddle in chrome, it looks fine. The height of the absolute position centered div is only tall enough to fit the text. However, in firefox, the div stretches all the way to the bottom of the container. Does anyone know what is causing this behavior in firefox, and what I can do to have consistency? The display has to be flex.

Things look great in chrome, but firefox is boggling my mind, and I couldn't find anything online that seemed to have the same problem.

Source code
HTML:

```html
<div class="zero">
   <div class="one">Test</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.one {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  height: -moz-fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto
}

.zero {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I notice

- `diplay: felx;` there is a typo. It must be `flex`
- `height: fitcontent` will not work because of this `top: 0; bottom: 0;`
- `.one` to be `absolute` in `.zero`, `.zero` must have `position: relative;`

Comment: Thanks for the catches on the typo. I updated the fiddle and the problem I described still stands. Would you be able to expand on the second bullet you made? Why does it not work in firefox? It does work in chrome.

Comment: The parent .zero already fill all the page with width: 100%; and height: 100%;. So the child .one being absolute, when it must start from top: 0; to end at bottom: 0; this implies that .one will take the whole height of it's parent, which already took 100% of the page. So the height: fitcontent; will not work

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, but that still odes not answer why it works in chrome, but not safari (in chrome, the height is only as tall as it needs to be to fit the content while in firefox it stretches).

Comment: Either your Chrome browser or Firefox has cached a previous version of your css file and is not reloading the updates anymore. Try clearing their recent caches and you'll see that the result is the same on both browsers

Comment: So the fiddle works for you on firefox with my code changes? The div doesn't stretch to the top and bottom?